# Python timestamp in dataframe - convert into data format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have dataframe in following format:

```
    >     buyer_id   purch_id   timestamp  

    >     buyer_2    purch_2    1330767282
    >     buyer_3    purch_3    1330771685
    >     buyer_3    purch_4    1330778269
    >     buyer_4    purch_5    1330780256
    >     buyer_5    purch_6    1330813517
```

I want to ask for your advice how to convert timestamp column (in dataframe) into datetime and then extract only the time of the event into the new column??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming 'timestamp' is [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (seconds since the epoch), you can cast [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) provided the right unit ('s') and use the `time` part:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s').dt.time

df
Out[9]: 
  buyer_id purch_id   timestamp      time
0  buyer_2  purch_2  1330767282  09:34:42
1  buyer_3  purch_3  1330771685  10:48:05
2  buyer_3  purch_4  1330778269  12:37:49
3  buyer_4  purch_5  1330780256  13:10:56
4  buyer_5  purch_6  1330813517  22:25:17
```